# Span insertion in Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

There is a post that is on StackOverflow that explains how to change the style of a radio button: [Styling radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25590269/styling-radio-button?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Here's the code provided in that post:

```css
input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

.graphical-radio {
    background: gray;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + .graphical-radio {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input class="wpProQuiz_questionInput" type="radio" name="question_1_2" value="3" />
            <span class="graphical-radio"></span>
            Non riesco a lasciarlo solo
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It explains that I have first to insert a `<span>` after each radio button but I have no idea how insert a `<span>`.

How do I insert `<span>` in every possible answer in Wordpress?

Comment: @Riccardo79 Do you have the solution  ? thanks !

Comment: That solution is only one way of styling your radio buttons. there are many other ways and techniques. just do a simple google search , here is a link where you don't need to add span or anything: https://codepen.io/AngelaVelasquez/pen/Eypnq

Comment: this also help you..http://codepen.io/KenanYusuf/pen/PZKEKd   & http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nxqD4/1/